# How to make a function update the value of angular inputs

Tags: javascript, html, angular

When I select one of the cards on the page below, I wish to have the value of the inputs updated with values from a JSON object

[image: Example]

The json:

```json
{
  "status": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "pessoa_id": 75505,
      "created_at": "2022-02-01T17: 42: 46.000000Z",
      "holder": "LEONARDO LIMA",
      "validade": "2026-06-01",
      "bandeira": "Mastercard"
    }
  ]
}
```

The json value is on the variable "responseData"

```js
renderTokenCard() {
  this.mundipaggS.checkToken().subscribe((response: any) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
    this.cartS.tokenCard = response;
    this.responseData = response;
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)));
  },);
}
```

the function that is linked to the select action:

```js
SelecionarCartao() {
  this.mundipaggS.postToken(this.responseData)

  console.log(this.responseData)
}
```

I wanted to get the responseData value and make a post for the postToken

The HTML

```html
<div class="form-group ">
  <label for="ncartao">Número do cartão <span class="text-danger"> *</span></label>
  <input name="card-number" maxlength="19" #cardNumber formControlName="digiNumero" id="ncartao" type="text"
    class="form-control col-lg-6  ">
</div>

<div class="form-group">

  <label for="nomeimpresso">Nome <b>impresso</b> no cartão<span class="text-danger"> *</span></label>
  <input #nomeImpresso formControlName="digiNome" name="holder-name" id="nomeimpresso" class="form-control col-lg-6"
    type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: Please share your HTML code as well.

Comment: follows an example of the html cards part, with the
Número do cartão *
Nome impresso no cartão *
On the principal post
@JulianLiu

Comment: What is the name of your formGroup variable? And what values from the json would you like to place in the form inputs?

Answer (score 0):

"Think in functions". If you has a function like

```
getGroup(data:any=null)
{
  //data will be the properties by defect and, using spread operator,
  //replace the properties by the data object 

  data={
      id: 0,
      pessoa_id:0,
      created_at:"",
      holder: "",
      validade: "",
      bandeira:"",
      ...data
  }

  return new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(data.id),
      pessoa_id: new FormControl(data.pessoa_id),
      created_at:new FormControl(data.created_at),,
      holder: new FormControl(data.holder),,
      validade: new FormControl(data.validade),,
      bandeira:new FormControl(data.bandeira),}
  })
}
```

Each change in "Meus Cartoes"

```
change(bandeira:string)
{
  const data=this.responseData.data.find(x=>x.bandeira==bandeira)
  if (data)
     this.form=getGroup(data) //<--a form with all the data
  else
     this.form=getGroup({bandeira:bandeira}) //<--a form with the "bandeira"
}
```

NOTE: really the "form" need split the "validate", get the "numero do cartao" and the "nome_impreso"...